# Witchblade - watch the film before the TV series?

Tags: movie, tv, suggested-order, witchblade

I was looking for something new to watch and happened to stumble across a Witchblade movie and TV series.

Are the film and series completely separate, or is the film a lead-in into the TV series?

Will I spoil anything by watching the film followed by the series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the movie you refer to is [this](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0169514/), and the TV series is [this](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0274298/), then yes they're connected.  The movie is just the pilot of the series, and as such should be watched before starting the series. [Wiki source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Witchblade_%28TV_series%29_episodes)

On the other hand, if you're referring to the unrelated [anime](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0813971/), as far as I know, that's not linked to any movie.